# Adding columns and rows in CSS

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am still new to web development and use WordPress. Calculated Field Forms plugin will only allow 4 columns so I need to create a custom stylesheet for this particular form. Now I have tried starting with very simple  or  basic explanation of how it is supposed to work.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<style>
</style>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="column">
        Column
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        Column
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        Column
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

It is supposed to give me 1 row with 3 columns. But instead I get 1 column and 3 rows. In total I need 1 row with 7 columns representing the 7 days of the week. I keep finding stuff that will work, but nothing that helps explain why I am getting the results that I am getting. Thanks for anyone's help and patience as I am still learning HTML and CSS.

Comment: That's just your HTML. Where's your CSS? You can technically just put your row class in a ```display: flex``` but it'd be helpful to see what you have.

Comment: does style.css include bootstrap in it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using display flex:

```css
.row {
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<style>
</style>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="column">
        Column
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        Column
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        Column
      </div>
     <div class="column">
        Column
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        Column
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        Column
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        Column
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is an example with the classes you used being styled by bootstrap:

```css
.row{justify-content: space-between;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<style>
</style>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="column">
        Column
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        Column
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        Column
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        Column
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        Column
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        Column
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        Column
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```